# MediaPlayer delayed a few seconds before onComplete got called on some devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I tried to play a local mp4 video file on my TV Box. I found a weird issue with MediaPlayer's playback speed. Here're my logs:

```
19:30:09.346 E/MediaPlayerManager: currentMediaPlayer's duration = 16021
19:30:09.715 E/MediaPlayerManager: setOnInfoListener - MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START
19:30:27.982 E/MediaPlayerManager: onComplete
```

The media duration was 16s, but it took about 18s to complete the video's playback. There's always a 2s delay before the `onComplete` listener got called. Does anyone have a solution for this?

After some experiments, I found out the issue was the large `SurfaceView`. If I replaced it with a `TextureView` or create the `SurfaceView` with smaller size, there's no extra delays.

P/s: I knew ExoPlayer, but for some specific reason, I could not use it.

Comment: Strange! on which Android version you have noticed it ?

Comment: @metalfight-user868766 my tv box is x96 max plus. The os is Android 9.